# What Pattern I should use for below scenario

Tags: vb.net, design-patterns

1. MainPage -> News.
2. MainPage -> SubPages -> News.

for MainPage I use facade Pattern.
and to get the data from the webpage I use HtmlAgility in vb .net.

For iteration, please suggest me pattern, I need a pattern, which only
initalize the SUBPAGE or NEWS when iterate, through for each block.

with regard

Comment: Scraping websites (using HtmlAgilityPack) really doesn't have anything to do with Design Patterns unless you explain the broader-context. It sounds like you're following Cargo Cult Programming: you don't know what Design Patterns are, yet you want them anyway, shoe-horning them into your program code somehow.

Comment: KEEP IT SAMPLE: Tell me a suitable pattern, for iteration, which is initialized when accessed.
- suppose we have a main class auction. and a subclasses cars. lets suppose 1000 cars.
. now I want a suitable pattern when I goto each car, then only that car is initalize ( not all 1000 ). hope it help.

Answer (score 0):

Iterator Pattern, is looking good match in above scenario, using aggregator during traversing. If anyone have think some other pattern is good, please comment.

Comment: Adil please close your laptop and Return to sleep, Tomorrow all should be more clear